# Reading multiple files in Python by using parser (need a short lesson)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

As self education day of the week I was playing around with parser utility in python.

I made some progress also, but I am stuck with a very silly problem.

**`The problem:`** I have an input file which has one only one column (and n number of rows) and I have m number of dictionary files. I want to extract the values of the terms (in my input file) from the different dictionaries.

Input file is:

```
SGIP1
SLC45A1
NECAP2
AGBL4
```

dictionary file 1

```
NM_032291   chr1    66999824    67210768    0   SGIP1   4694    6   1.0586e-02
NM_001080397    chr1    8384389 8404227 0   SLC45A1 2401    0   0.0000e+00
NM_018090   chr1    16767166    16786584    0   NECAP2  2081    3673    1.4617e+01
NM_032785   chr1    48998526    50489626    -0  AGBL4   2988    0   0.0000e+00
NM_001145278    chr1    16767166    16786584    0   NECAP2  2003    3534    1.4612e+01
NM_013943   chr1    25071759    25170815    0   CLIC4   4434    5646    1.0545e+01
NM_001145277    chr1    16767166    16786584    0   NECAP2  2005    3504    1.4473e+01
NM_052998   chr1    33546713    33585995    0   ADC 2182    4   1.5182e-02
NM_001195683    chr1    92145899    92351836    -0  TGFBR3  6464    59  7.5590e-02
```

dictionary file2

```
NM_032291   chr1    66999824    67210768    +   SGIP1   4694    44  9.5755e-02
NM_001080397    chr1    8384389 8404227 +   SLC45A1 2401    4   1.7018e-02
NM_018090   chr1    16767166    16786584    +   NECAP2  2081    1815    8.9095e+00
NM_032785   chr1    48998526    50489626    -   AGBL4   2988    4   1.3675e-02
NM_001145278    chr1    16767166    16786584    +   NECAP2  2003    1760    8.9760e+00
NM_013943   chr1    25071759    25170815    +   CLIC4   4434    3859    8.8906e+00
NM_001145277    chr1    16767166    16786584    +   NECAP2  2005    1719    8.7581e+00
NM_052998   chr1    33546713    33585995    +   ADC 2182    14  6.5543e-02
NM_001195683    chr1    92145899    92351836    -   TGFBR3  6464    49  7.7436e-02
```

The dictionary files can be 1 or many depending upon the user and can have many rows.

If the value in column 6 of dictionary file matches the value in input file and value in column 8 of dictionary is more than 5. It should print column 6 and column 9 and assemble the result in one final file as:

```
SGIP1   1.0586e-02  9.5755e-02
NECAP2  1.4617e+01  8.9095e+00
NECAP2  1.4612e+01  8.9760e+00
```

This is the format I require.

**What have I done:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess
import math
from optparse import OptionParser,OptionGroup

VERSION = "1.0  "

########process the options##########

usage = "usage: %prog -l <FILE> -i <FILE>,<FILE>,<FILE>....... -n <STRING> "
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-l", "--genelist file", dest="input_file", help="one string per line", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-i", "--RNASeq files (separted by comma)", dest="data_file", help="RNASeq file generated from Arjen's Script", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-n", "--name", dest="name", help="Name of output file", metavar="STRING")
parser.add_option_group(group1)
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
####check whether all files & scripts are present####
if not options.input_file or not options.name:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)
####reading input file ######

for item in open(options.input_file):

    item=item.replace("\n","")

#######reading of data file and matching the components and assembling in final file##########

This is where I am lost I dont know how to do it, the datafiles if more than 1 will be seperated by comma's.


I have done similar thing with quick and dirty solution for one data file, The code for which is below (incase needed)


#! /usr/bin/python
inputfile="genelist.txt"
rnafile="datafile.txt"
for item in open(inputfile):

    item=item.replace("\n","")
    for line in open(rnafile):
        line = line.split("\t")
        if line[5] == item:
            print (line[5] + "\t" + line[8].replace("\n",""))
```

Could anyone of you please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: All files have multiple occurrences of eg. `NECAP2`. It is not clear how that should be dealt with. Also, why does `SGIP1` appear in output but not in input?

Comment: multiple occurences are fine (just take the one that qualifies the criterion of >5), SGIP1 has been added to the input_file (it was error from my side).

Comment: Both dictionary files now contain all the information that you input file does, is there any specific need to process it?

Comment: Wait, let me alter the input file. These are just a sample file actual data is much bigger in size (in actual data each dictionary files may contain 42 thousand lines and input file may contain some thing from 10 items to few thousand).

Comment: Ok, I think I know what should be happening here. One more question though, does the order of the input file have any significance or is it just a list of strings to process?

Comment: No order does not matter of the input file (The input file must only have have one name per line). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my untested code below. This should just about do what you are looking for, bar exception handling and some possible formatting issues:

```
# edit - have to remove trailing \n from input lines
valid_items = [ line.strip() for line in open('input') ]

with open('dictionary1') as dict1:

  for dict2_line in open('dictionary2'):
    dict1_line = dict1.readline()

    # protect against dict1 being shorter
    if dict1_line == '':
      break

    fields1 = dict1_line.split()
    if fields1[5] in valid_items and int(fields1[7]) > 5:
      fields2 = dict2_line.split()
      print(fields1[5].ljust(8) + fields1[8] + '  ' + fields2[8])
```

Not that using split without arguments splits on any whitespace, doesn't produce empty fields and should remove the trailing newline. This is probably what you are looking for since the separators in your example aren't consistent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if in case of more than two dictionaries. the number of dictionary depends upon the user, I cannot prefix it :(

Comment: Is all you are really doing with the additional dictionaries just printing the last field. Everything else depends on the first, right?

Comment: yes printing the last field and everything depends whether the 7 field in all dictionaries was more than 5. that's all :) . One more request please try o integrate your code into mine as yours is not using parser. Thank you